# Unity 5 Exporting Custom Aspect Ratio Not Working

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, I've added a fixed resolution game size (1073x327). Under Player Settings when I export it I've also set the default screen width and height to the aforementioned values and chose 'Other' under Supported Aspect Ratio however when I export and play, the only option I get is 1280x768 and a lot of the sides of my game are cut off. How exactly to get the exported game to run with my defined resolution?

Same question here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/673583/custom-resolution-and-aspect-ratio.html

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: you don't even mention what platform you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're building out for desktop, because you mention the ability to choose the resolution (though it's only the one).

The resolutions that the build shows you are the resolutions that your monitor can support. If you cannot get 1073x327 to show up, it means your monitor is not capable of running that resolution on full-screen.

You could, however, find different ways to make it run at your intended resolution with black edges. Easy approaches involve using the game camera appropriately!

I hope that helps!

Comment: Sigh, that's quite depressing. Luckily I didn't have much going in the scene anyway so rescaling and so won't be that much of a problem. Sorry, I forgot to mention which platform I'm that was my mistake. Thanks :)